# Axios get response is not carried over into state [Native React]

Tags: react-native, axios

first question here.

when i try to run this, it does fetch data in the response.data, but that data is not set into state to be passed through as prop to another page and it always stays [Object object] or [undefined] & i have no clue what's going wrong

```
 state = {
    APiData: {},
    userInput: "cheese",
    onCall: false
}


findFood = () => {
    let self = this;
    let userInput = this.state.userInput.toLowerCase();
    let url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?query=" + userInput + "&number=1&apiKey="+apiKey;
    axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);  //get's data
            self.setState({APIdata: response.data});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
}

renderbody = () => {
    console.log(this.state.APIdata) //this thing, is undefined
       // return (<SearchBody data={this.state.APIdata} key={apiKey}/>)
}
```

this is the data in response.data

```
  "baseUri": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/",
  "expires": 1585843318293,
  "isStale": false,
  "number": 1,
  "offset": 0,
  "processingTimeMs": 437,
  "results": Array [
    Object {
      "id": 215435,
      "image": "three-cheese-pizza-for-cheese-lovers-215435.jpg",
      "imageUrls": Array [
        "three-cheese-pizza-for-cheese-lovers-215435.jpg",
      ],
      "readyInMinutes": 45,
      "servings": 8,
      "title": "Three-Cheese Pizza (For Cheese Lovers)",
    },
  ],
  "totalResults": 855,
}
Object {
  "baseUri": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/",
  "expires": 1585843318293,
  "isStale": false,
  "number": 1,
  "offset": 0,
  "processingTimeMs": 437,
  "results": Array [
    Object {
      "id": 215435,
      "image": "three-cheese-pizza-for-cheese-lovers-215435.jpg",
      "imageUrls": Array [
        "three-cheese-pizza-for-cheese-lovers-215435.jpg",
      ],
      "readyInMinutes": 45,
      "servings": 8,
      "title": "Three-Cheese Pizza (For Cheese Lovers)",
    },
  ],
  "totalResults": 855,
}
```

Comment: For `undefined` case, you need to add some code to handle it, because the api you are calling will not always give you what you are asking for. So for `response.data` this part, try to check if it's `undefined` first and give it default value if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You are not using state. Your state needs to be inside your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       APiData: {},
       userInput: "cheese",
       onCall: false
   }
}
```

Then, you just need to call `this.setState({ APIdata: response.data });`

I would recommend you to use [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org) to get data using this.props.